# Python statsmodels ARIMA LinAlgError: SVD did not converge

Tags: python, statsmodels

Background: I'm developing a program using statsmodels that fits 27 arima models (p,d,q=0,1,2) to over 100 variables and chooses the model with the lowest aic and statistically significant t-statistics for the AR/MA coefficients and statistically significant p-values for the dickey fuller test...

For one particular variable and one particular set of parameters, I get

```
LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

for replication, the variable and the code that fails are below

```
rollrate =[0.3469842191781748,
 0.9550689157572028,
 0.48170862494888256,
 0.15277985674197356,
 0.46102487817508747,
 0.32777706854320243,
 0.5163787896482797,
 0.01707716528127215,
 0.015036662424309755,
 0.2299825242910243,
 0.03719773802216722,
 0.24392098372995807,
 0.1783587055969874,
 0.6759904243574179,
 0.1197617555878022,
 0.04274682226635633,
 0.27369984820298465,
 0.18999355015483932,
 0.2985208240580264,
 0.2872064881442138,
 1.0522764728046277,
 0.3694114556631419,
 0.09613536093441034,
 0.6648215681632191,
 0.3223120091564835,
 0.9274048223872483,
 0.2763221143255601,
 0.4501460109958479,
 0.2220472247972312,
 0.3644512582291407,
 0.7790042237519584,
 0.3749145302678043,
 1.2771681290160286,
 0.6760112486224217,
 0.5214358465170098,
 0.84041997296269,
 0.12054593136059581,
 0.18900376737686622,
 0.042561102427304424,
 0.17189805124670604,
 0.11383752243305952,
 0.2687780002387387,
 0.717538770963329,
 0.26636160206108384,
 0.04221743047344771,
 0.3259506533106764,
 0.20146525340606328,
 0.4059344185647537,
 0.07503287726465639,
 0.3011594076817088,
 0.1433563136989911,
 0.14803562944375281,
 0.23096999679467808,
 0.31133672787599703,
 0.2313639154827471,
 0.30343086620083537,
 0.4608439884577555,
 0.19149827372467804,
 0.2506814947310181,
 1.008458195025946,
 0.3776434264127751,
 0.344728062930179,
 0.2110402015365776,
 0.26582041849423843,
 1.1019000121595244,
 0.0,
 0.023068095385979804,
 0.014256779894199491,
 0.3209225608633755,
 0.00294468492742426,
 0.0,
 0.3346732726544143,
 0.38256681208088283,
 0.4916019617068597,
 0.06922156984602362,
 0.34458053250016984,
 0.0,
 0.09615667784109984,
 1.8271531669931351,
 0,
 0,
 0.0,
 0,
 0.0,
 0.03205594450156685,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0.0,
 0,
 0.0,
 0,
 0.0,
 0,
 0,
 1.0,
 0]


p=2
q=2
d=0
fit = statsmodels.api.tsa.ARIMA(rollRate, (p,d,q)).fit(transparams=False)
```

I understand that the particular parameters p=2,d=2,q=0 may be a terrible ARIMA model for this particular variable and that the variable itself may not be a suitable candidate for an ARIMA model due to the many zeroes or unstationary qualities, but I need a way to possibly bypass this error or fix the issue in order to keep the program iterating through parameters. Thanks

Comment: Why not simply catch the LinAlgError in a `try-except` block? This way you accept that for some parameter combinations your selected model cannot be fitted.

Comment: I actually have a try-except block for a ValueError already so adding the LinAlgError was one of the first things i tried `try: fit = statsmodels.api.tsa.ARIMA(rollRate, (p,d,q)).fit(transparams=False) except (ValueError, LinAlgError): pass` but i get a `NameError: name 'LinAlgError' is not defined`

Comment: Don't forget to import `LinAlgError` to your namespace: `from numpy.linalg import LinAlgError`

Comment: You can see the approach I took here in `_safe_arma_fit`. It also handles the cases of non-convergence due to bad starting parameters. All pretty naive though. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.py#L935

Comment: Thanks j and cel. I'll try to apply the approach you took using ARIMA instead of arma...I know this is all naive, I'd rather use auto.arima, but i'm having trouble downloading rpy2 due to enterprise firewall

Comment: did `_safe_arma_fit` work ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe consider trying this way as this is a combination of methods I learned from Jason Brownlee (PhD), Machine Learning Mastery

https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/

and Farhad Malik, Mathematician

https://towardsdatascience.com/forecasting-exchange-rates-using-arima-in-python-f032f313fc56

By combining their methods and techniques, I was able to come up with what I believe is close to a working and reliable model.

Here is the code I stitched together somewhat painfully for many hours:

```
import warnings
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
from matplotlib import pyplot

rollRate=[0.3469842191781748,0.9550689157572028,0.48170862494888256,0.15277985674197356,0.46102487817508747,0.32777706854320243,
0.5163787896482797,0.01707716528127215,0.015036662424309755,0.2299825242910243,0.03719773802216722,0.24392098372995807,
0.1783587055969874,0.6759904243574179,0.1197617555878022,
0.04274682226635633,0.27369984820298465,0.18999355015483932,0.2985208240580264,0.2872064881442138,1.0522764728046277,
0.3694114556631419,0.09613536093441034,0.6648215681632191,0.3223120091564835,0.9274048223872483,0.2763221143255601,
0.4501460109958479,0.2220472247972312,0.3644512582291407,0.7790042237519584,0.3749145302678043,
1.2771681290160286,0.6760112486224217,0.5214358465170098,0.84041997296269,0.12054593136059581,
0.18900376737686622,0.042561102427304424,0.17189805124670604,0.11383752243305952,0.2687780002387387,
0.717538770963329,0.26636160206108384,0.04221743047344771,0.3259506533106764,0.20146525340606328,0.4059344185647537,
0.07503287726465639,0.3011594076817088,0.1433563136989911,0.14803562944375281,0.23096999679467808,
0.31133672787599703,0.2313639154827471,0.30343086620083537,0.4608439884577555,0.19149827372467804,
0.2506814947310181,1.008458195025946,0.3776434264127751,0.344728062930179,0.2110402015365776,0.26582041849423843,
1.1019000121595244,0.0,0.023068095385979804,0.014256779894199491,0.3209225608633755,0.00294468492742426,0.0,
0.3346732726544143,0.38256681208088283,0.4916019617068597,0.06922156984602362,0.34458053250016984,0.0,
0.09615667784109984,1.8271531669931351,0,0,0.0,0,0.0,0.03205594450156685,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0,0.0,0,0,1.0,0]

# Evaluate an ARIMA model for a given order (p,d,q) and return RMSE
def evaluate_arima_model(X, arima_order):
    # prepare training dataset
    X = X.astype('float32')
    train_size = int(len(X) * 0.50)
    train, test = X[0:train_size], X[train_size:]
    history = [x for x in train]
    # make predictions
    predictions = list()
    for t in range(len(test)):
        model = ARIMA(history, order=arima_order)
        # model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
        model_fit = model.fit(trend='nc', disp=0)
        yhat = model_fit.forecast()[0]
        predictions.append(yhat)
        history.append(test[t])
    # calculate out of sample error
    rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(test, predictions))
    return rmse

# evaluate combinations of p, d and q values for an ARIMA model
def evaluate_models(dataset, p_values, d_values, q_values):
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
    best_score, best_cfg = float("inf"), None
    for p in p_values:
        for d in d_values:
            for q in q_values:
                order = (p, d, q)
                try:
                    rmse = evaluate_arima_model(dataset, order)
                    print(rmse)
                    if rmse < best_score:
                        best_score, best_cfg = rmse, order
                    print('ARIMA%s RMSE=%.3f' % (order, rmse))
                except:
                    continue
    print('Best ARIMA%s RMSE=%.3f' % (best_cfg, best_score))

p_values = range(0, 2)
d_values = range(0, 1)
q_values = range(0, 2)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

dataset = pd.Series([356,386,397,397,413,458,485,344,390,360,420,435,439,454,462,454,469,500,492,473,458,469,481,
          488,466,462,473,530,662,651,587,515,526,503,503,503,515,522,492,503,503,450,432,432,458,462,
          503,488,466,492,503,515,500,522,575,583,587,628,640,609,606,632,617,613,598,575,564,549,538,
          568,575,579,587,602,594,587,587,625,613])

dataset = dataset.values
print('\n==============================\n')
evaluate_models(dataset, p_values, d_values, q_values)

pp = 2
dd = 1
qq = 2

def StartProducingARIMAForecastValues(dataVals, p, d, q):
    model = ARIMA(dataVals, order=(p, d, q))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
    pred = model_fit.forecast()[0]
    return pred

print('\n==============================\n')

predictions = StartProducingARIMAForecastValues(rollRate, 1, 1, 0)
print('First Prediction=%f' % (predictions))

Actual = [x for x in rollRate]
Predictions = list()

for timestamp in range(len(rollRate)):
    ActualValue = rollRate[timestamp]
    Prediction = StartProducingARIMAForecastValues(Actual, 3, 1, 0)
    print('Actual=%f, Predicted=%f' % (ActualValue, Prediction))

    Predictions.append(Prediction)
    Actual.append(ActualValue)

Error = mean_squared_error(rollRate, Predictions)

print('Test Mean Squared Error : %.3f' % Error)
# plot
pyplot.plot(rollRate)
pyplot.plot(Predictions, color='red')
pyplot.show()
```

and the output graph:

[image]

and the output itself:

[image]

[image]